# Remove table-hover effect from some row of the table?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is html:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-hover">
    ....
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat-end ng-show="modelRow.activeRow==car.name" class="hidden-table">
        <td colspan="6">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-hover">
                <tr><td>{{car.name}}</td><td>{{car.review}}</td><td>{{car.rating}}</td><td>{{car.recommended}}</td></tr>
                <tr><td>{{car.name}}</td><td>{{car.review}}</td><td>{{car.rating}}</td><td>{{car.recommended}}</td></tr>
                <tr><td>{{car.name}}</td><td>{{car.review}}</td><td>{{car.rating}}</td><td>{{car.recommended}}</td></tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

This is a hidden row that contains an html table inside of it and shows up when you click on some row on the table.

But when my hidden table inside of a row is showing up and you point a mouse on it, it changes the background color, but I don't need that. I have tried to fix this with following css:

```
 .hidden-table:hover {
     background-color: none !important;
 }
```

But it didn't work. **So, what is the right way to remove table-hover effect from some row of the table?**

Comment: I have also tried to add `hidden-table` class to the table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`background-color: none;` doesn't exist... It should be transparent. But this won't work for you because you will have the color of the tr...

So you will have to set a color like :

```
.hidden-table:hover {
     background-color: white !important;
 }
```

EDIT:

As your table also has the bootstrap classes table-hover and other, you will have to override this properties :

```
.table-hover > tbody > tr:hover > td
```

So something like :

```
.table-hover > tbody > tr.hidden-table:hover > td {
     background-color: white;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

> This works for me perfectly on chrome

```
table tr:hover td { 
   background-color: inherit;     
   opacity: 1.0;
}
```